# Google Apps Script - How can i get the content of a page?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, xmlhttprequest, google-sheets, google-apps

When i try to use the **XMLHttpRequest()** function in a google script, i get an error telling me the element is undefined.
Is there another way to get the content of a page using google script.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The closest thing to `XMLHttpRequest` is probably [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).  Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you can also call [server-side functions from the client side](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-communication).

Comment: Can you post your code of how you're using XmlHttpRequest. As Tim suggested, you can use UrlFetchApp too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is limited to avoid the ability to redirect people visiting a publicly (and trusted) document which would fetch data accessible on your browser (using your login sessions and etc).

Make sure you set the [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) headers as specified in the W3 specification to allow external services to query your request handler.

See the page here for more limitations: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#xmlhttprequests_xhr

Comment: Thank you for highlight. I'm going to find a workaround for this problem.